# Django-Mongo Migration

Tags: django, mongodb, django-south

In my `Django` project i have used `mysql`as my database engine and `south` for migration.

Now i need to use `MongoDB` in my project as second database. I have written database routers to use two database at a time.
`python manage.py syncdb--database='db_2'` is working fine its creating all tables in new db_2 database.

Now the real problem is if i want to add any field in existing table. How can i do it as `south dose not support MongoDB`. Is there any other way to work on migration . I really need to integrate `MongoDB` with `Django` for using `ORM` in my project

Comment: MongoDB doesn't even have fields. There is no need for migrations.

Comment: But i need to use orm to access all its keys